# SQL duplicate data for same group

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables:

TableA

```
a  b  r1
c  d  r4 
e  f  r6
```

TableB

```
r1  g1
r2  g1
r3  g1 
r4  g2 
r5  g2
```

How can I get next:

```
a  b  r1 
a  b  r2
a  b  r3 
c  d  r4
c  d  r5
```

For each r[i] from TableA find it in TableB and for each r[j] from TableB that have the same g[k] (same group) duplicate data from TableA.

Comment: I'm confused; those are HTML tables, not database tables. Do you have actual HTML tables represented as strings in your database or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to `b` twice:

```
select a.*, bg.col1
from a join
     b
     on a.col3 = b.col1 join
     b bg
     on b.col3 = bg.col3;
```